# How do I override how the ReturnUrl query string parameter value is set?

Tags: .net, asp.net, forms-authentication

If a user requests a page when they're not authenticated they are redirected to a login page with a return URL in the query string. However, the return URL is a physical resource but in our application we use virtual resources which map to physical resources using URL rewriting.

So if the user originally requested:

```
http://foo.com/bar/Pages/Performance/Employee/Summary.aspx?ID=1104
```

After logging in the call to `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` will redirect them to:

```
http://foo.com/bar/Pages/Performance/Summary.aspx?ID=1104
```

That's assuming that the page is physically located in Pages/Performance.

How do I change the way the ReturnUrl parameter is set?

Comment: Possibly this similar question can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828098/how-to-elegantly-handle-returnurl-when-using-urlrewrite-in-asp-net-2-0-webforms