# URL rewriting with global.asax causing issue on button click in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing, global-asax

I am using global file to rewrite URL, rewriting works fine for other url just one rule is not working which makes all ajax/button clicks stop. All my button clicks works fine when i use:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("BusinessDetails", "bd/{PageUrl}", "~/business-details.aspx")
```

But I don't want this type of url:`www.mywebsite/com/bd/business` I need this `www.mywebsite.com/business` for this am using

```
routes.MapPageRoute("BusinessDetails", "{PageUrl}", "~/business-details.aspx")
```

But this stops all button clicks though I get the needed URL and site works just stops all button clicks/update panel/validation.

I need this url to work with all button clicks
`www.mywebsite/com/business` or `www.mywebsite.com/business/`

Tried using

`routes.Ignore("{webresource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")` for button click as was getting error in console

> 'Unexpected token <' in webresource.axd

Also tried

```
routes.MapPageRoute("BusinessDetails1", "{PageUrl}/{categoryName}", "~/business-details.aspx", false, New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.categoryName = "home"}))
```

And also when I click on button it says in console

> 'Page_ClientValidate is not defined'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your route entry well be capturing all page requests and passing them to business-details.aspx

Have you tried using:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("BusinessDetails", "business", "~/business-details.aspx")
```

This will then only map www.mywebsite.com/business to the business-details.aspx page.

Also, assuming that your business-details.aspx page is Webforms, you will need to make sure that the Form Action URL is set correctly - if you are not familiar with doing this, then see this post for information on how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/a/1847623/806756

Comment: {PageUrl} will be dynamic values which will be coming so cant use "business".. its just to make this work it need 2params like Business/{PageUrl}

Comment: So the business-details.aspx page handles all the content pages you want to serve?  In that case, can you provide information on how this page is set up?  The "Unexepected token" error would then suggest it might be posting back to the wrong URL.   also, try using Chrome dev tools to see the Network traffic and which URL the button click is actually loading